# Mixing ints and function pointers in python dict values

Tags: python, dictionary, function-pointers, state-machine

I'm making a finite state machine to iterate over some text for speaker, verb, and quote identification. Everything is going fine, but I'm frustrated I cannot get my dictionary to work just the way I want it to. I want to use a dictionary like this, that has both function pointers and ints as values:

```
chars = ['a','b','c']
whatever = ['cheese']
state = 0

def function():
    # don't know what's going on, ask user to check

transitions = {
0: {chars: 1, whatever: 2, '“': 4},
1: {chars: 3, '“': function},
etc.
}

for item in data:
    for transition in transitions[state]:
        if item in transition or transition in item:
            state = transitions[state][item]
```

However, this code doesn't call the function if it finds it, or if I have it call the function, it errors on calling an int.

PS I'm not looking to use a library, etc.

Comment: This code will not even compile: you can't have a list has a dictionary key (and it should be `def function():`, but I guess that's just a typo).  `state` is used as an index on the rhs without being defined.

Comment: Yes! Just typos, sorry. I fixed them. I was sort of quickly copy/pasting + generalizing my code too late at night, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the object type to decide what to do with it. I don't want to get into other issues with the code, but for the basic idea, here's a function that returns an int or calls a function depending on the value type.

```
def action(value):
    if isinstance(value, int):
        return value
    elif callable(value):
        return value()
    else:
        raise ValueError("action does not work with %s objects" % type(value))
```

Comment: @Brian - oops, I sure did.

Comment: Of course: I didn't think of this. Right now I have my code doing this as an if/else in the code, but I wanted to make it a bit more compact and self-contained inside the dictionary.